# My method that adds a new node to the end of a linked list keeps throwing NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, singly-linked-list

sorry if this formatted a bit oddly, this is my first time asking a question here. I am working on a method for my class that is supposed to add a new node containing a specified value to the end of a linked list. However I keep seeing a NullPointerException at the start of my while loop. I would really appreciate any insight.

```
public void add(Anything value)
{      
    Node temp = first;
    if (temp==null) {
        this.addFirst(value);
    }
    while(temp.next!=null){
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    temp.next=new Node(value, null);
}
```

Note: for the purposes of this assignment I am only creating methods, the assignment is preloaded with some code already that I am not allowed to change. I have attached it to provide some more detail.

```
public class CS2LinkedList<Anything>
{  
    // the Node class is a private inner class used (only) by the LinkedList class
    private class Node
    {
        private Anything data;
        private Node next;
        
        public Node(Anything a, Node n)
        {
            data = a;
            next = n;
        }
    }
    
    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    
    
    public CS2LinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (first == null);
    }
    
    public void addFirst(Anything d)
    {
         Node temp = first;
         first = new Node(d,temp);
    }
    
    
    public void clear()
    {
        first = null;
    }
    
    public boolean contains(Anything value)
    {
        for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
        {
            if (value.equals(curr.data)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();  //String result = "";
        for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
            result.append(curr.data + "->");  //result = result + curr.data + "->";
        result.append("[null]");
        return result.toString();   //return result + "[null]";
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't gone through all the codes, but this part has a problem.

```java
Node temp = first;
if (temp==null) {
    this.addFirst(value);
}
```

After this block, event if you put an instance to the `first` field, `temp` variable still remains as `null` because you haven't replaced it yet.

So when running the following code,

```
// temp is still null here
while(temp.next!=null){
    temp=temp.next;
}
```

`temp` is `null` and causes `temp.next` to raise a `NullPointerException`.

You can either reassign the value of `temp` as follows:

```java
Node temp = first;
if (temp==null) {
    this.addFirst(value);
    temp = first;
}
```

or just return if the `addFirst` method do all the jobs.

```java
Node temp = first;
if (temp==null) {
    this.addFirst(value);
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the code functions now but it also always returns two copies of what should be the first node, no matter how long the list. not to be a pain but do you have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Then you might be inserting the first node in `addFirst()` method. Calling this method will add a first node and after that, you will append one more node because you are doing `temp.next=new Node(value, null);`. Try the last snippet of my answer which returns after adding the first node.